# Generating Native Executables

Tags: file, cross-platform, executable

Is there a way that one can create native cross platform native executables (.exe, etc) using one language? Are C/C++ the only languages that compile to native executables or can other languages do the same? 
Note: I'm not looking for file types that require external software to be installed in order to run the program such as   jar,  py, and rb files.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends more on the compilers than the language. [Xojo](http://www.xojo.com), for one, compiles native executables for Windows, OS X and Linux from the same source code.